# Session lost after editing code behind file with IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-express

So I have a ASP.NET 4.0 web forms project that I am developing. My localhost web server is IIS  Express. If I edit an aspx file and hit save IIS Express reloads all symbols and clears the current session.

The behavior seems to be basically an iisreset and an app pool recycle.

This is slowing down development and testing and I would like to, at the very least, stop losing session if possible. I am not editing a code behind file just HTML in the .aspx file. This never happened when I used the Cassini web server

P.S. numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart is not the solution to my problem as the default value for that is 20.

Comment: This is a day-one behavior of ASP.NET and has nothing to do with IIS - express or otherwise.

Comment: When I used Cassini I feel like I could make an edit to my.aspx file and there was little to no delay on browser refresh to see my change. Now there is a 3 to 5 second delay.

Comment: Also, were you using Web Application Projects, or Web Site Projects (File->New Web Site)? There's a big difference.

Comment: I am using website projects...

Comment: Thats the reason. They're very strange

Comment: Funny you say that because I find Web Application Projects to be very strange in that the designer file does not automatically update when changes are made to the aspx or aspx code behind

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I moved ASP.NET to a database, that is more reliable anyways. The google search for this does not bring back a clear way to do this. Here is how to Configure SQL Server to Store ASP.NET Session State:

DO NOT RUN ANY SQL scripts manually. Go to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 and run the following command:

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -S [server]-U [username] -P [password] -d ASPState -ssadd -sstype c
```

If you are using integrated security include -E in your command execution instead of user name and password. Integrated security is where you will run into problems getting you ASP.NET session to work right. As far as I can tell you have to declare the database name in your cmd call to aspnet_regsql.exe so you can include the -sstype c option so you can get integrated security setup correctly. (by the way the default name Microsoft gives database is ASPState which I recommend you stick with). You also need to declare allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" in the web.config element you add within the `<system.web>` parent element. Ironically if you stick with the default name ASPState you do not need to declare the database name in the sqlConnectionString attribute even though allowCustomSqlDatabase attribute is directly related to having a custom name for your session state database.

```
 <sessionState
            mode="SQLServer"
            sqlConnectionString="Server=[database_ip];Trusted_Connection=true;"
            cookieless="false"
            timeout="20" 
            allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"
    />
```

You must give the following permissions to your Application Pool user in the database:
[take from this article](http://winmike.blogspot.com/2010/10/problems-with-sql-based-aspnet-state.html):

Add Application Pool user to User logins of ASPState database, associate him with db_datareader and db_datawriter roles

Open “Properties” dialog for ASPState database, select “Permissions” Tab and provide Application Pool user with EXECUTE/SELECT/INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE permissions for the ASPState database.